# What's the name of this construction?

Tags: java

I'm reading a code that I didn't write. I stumbled upon the following statement:

```
    context.checking(new org.jmock.Expectations() {
        {
            allowing(habilitationManager).hasRole(RoleDtoEnum.ROLE_NEWS);
            will(returnValue(true));
            allowing(habilitationManager).hasRole(RoleDtoEnum.ROLE_STAT);
            will(returnValue(true));
            allowing(habilitationManager).getUser();
            will(returnValue(getUserMock()));
            oneOf(parametreService).getParametre(PPP);
            will(returnValue(getMockPPP()));
        }
    });
```

I understand that the methods called inside the second `{ ... }` are `Expectations` methods.

- But how do you call this kind of code writing ?
- Especially how do you call the second `{ ... }` ?

Comment: I think this style of code is code that has a "fluent" interface, where it looks more like english language (or DSL-like) coding

Comment: @Jon IMO, it's easy and powerful to read this kind of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an anonymous class, with an instance initializer block in it. So to separate the two out:

```
// This is an anonymous class
Expectations expectations = new Expectations() {
    // Class body here
};

class Foo {

    // This is an instance initializer block in a normal class
    {
        System.out.println("You'll see this via either constructor");
    }

    Foo(int x) {}

    Foo(String y) {}
}
```

An [*instance initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) is implicitly called at the same time as instance variable initializers, in textual order, before the body of any constructor.

Comment: Why do you call `org.jmock.Expectations` an anonymous class ? In the jMock project, it's a concrete class. Sorry if I didn't precise the origin the `Expectations` class.

Comment: @Alex `new Expectations() { ... }` creates an instance of a subclass of Expectations. It's the subclass that's anonymous.

Comment: @fgb an instance of a subclass ??

Comment: @Alex: Yes. The anonymous class that the compiler generates is a subclass of `Expectations`, and when the code is executed, an instance of that anonymous class is created.

Comment: Ok guys, I was not aware of all this magic made by the compiler :)